# identifying office 365 users

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365

I want to identify if a user's email address is associated with an office 365 subscription.  I know that in one case I can query dns `dig example.com mx` and look for `.mail.protection.outlook.com.` in the output.  But that doesn't catch everyone.

Is there anything else I can do to identify which of my users should be able to log in with oauth2?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the domain of the email address you want to query and do a Get against

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

That will return the OpenID Connect metadata document which should have all the information you need to determine that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc